# React material ui snackbar always is the bottom how can i fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am trying to create a snackbar using material ui.
React version = 0.14
Material-ui version =0.15.0

I couldn't find anything suitable for this version of React so I decided to use material-ui. It works but only opens at the bottom of the screen. How can I change this? For example how can I get the top right.

My Code :

```
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

this.state = {
      open: false,
    };

 handleTouchTap = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
    });
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  };


 <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleTouchTap}> 
            SHOW NOTIFICATION
       <button>

        <Snackbar
          open={this.state.open}
          message="Event added to your calendar"
          autoHideDuration={4000}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        />
      </div>
```

Image is here : [Notification image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAbeX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `anchorOrigin` to update position:

```
<Snackbar
  ...
  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Viet. But material-ui 0.15.0 version is not accepted ı think because ı try it and dont work.

Comment: Yes. V0 doesn't support update position. Too out of date